# want to insert in attendence first time not update it

Tags: php, html

hi this is my code which updates an attendance system, but I dont know how to insert attendance for first time. Where should I use insert query? it also shows error and not updating the table. Somebody please guide me

```
<?php
    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") ordie(mysql_error()
    $db=mysql_select_db("Project") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT Fac_name FROM Faculty ORDER BY Fac_name ASC ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<form name="Attendence" method="post" action="A.php">
    <table style="text-align: left; padding: 5px;" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px; border: 1px #000000 solid;">Faculty Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px; border: 1px #000000 solid;">Abesent</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px; border: 1px #000000 solid;">Present</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px; border: 1px #000000 solid;">Total present</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>                                                   
            <tr>                                 
                <td class="table1">
                    <? $id[] = $rows['Fac_name']; ?><? echo $rows['Fac_name'];?>
                </td>
                <td class="table1">
                    <input name="date[<? echo $rows['Fac_name']; ?>]" type="text" >
                </td>                                                                                 
                <td id="present">
                    <input type="radio" name="Present[<? echo    $rows['Fac_name']; ?>]" checked="checked" >Present            
                </td>
                <td id="absent">
                    <input type="radio" name="Absent[<? echo      $rows['Fac_name']; ?>]" value="ABSENT">Absent
                </td>                              
                <td style="text-align: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px #000000 solid; height: 33px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;">
                <br><br>                                    
                    <input id="Submit" type="submit" name="Submit"   value="Insert" style="text-align: center; background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff;   border: 1px #000000 solid;">
                </td>
            </tr>                                                                                 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>   
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        foreach($_POST['Present'] as $id => $value) { 
            $date=$_POST['date'];
            $present=$_POST['Present'];
            $absent=$_POST['Absent'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Attendence(Fac_name, date, Present,  Absent) VALUES ('".$id."', '$date[$value]', '$present[$value]', '$absent[$value]', '".$value."') ";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);                           
        }
    }
    if($result) {
        //header("location:A.php");                                                      

    } else {
        //print_r ($_POST);
        echo "Your entry is not completed at this time.............";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submitattend'])) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $class1 = $_SESSION['bra'];
        $q3 = mysql_query("Select Id from `Faculty` order by `Id` ASC"); // get all roll numbers
        $count = mysql_num_rows($q3);
        $j = 1;
        while($q4 = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) {
        if(isset($_POST['chk'.$j])) {
            $v2 = $q7['finalattend']+1; //total attendance of student
            $v3 = $q7['totalattend']+1; //total attendance taken by teacher
            mysql_query("UPDATE `Attendence` SET `finalattend`='".$v2."',    `totalattend`='".$v3."' where `attenduser`='".$v1."'") or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            $v2=$q7['totalattend']+1;
                mysql_query("UPDATE `Attendence` SET `totalattend`='".$v2."' where `attenduser`='".$v1."'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        $j=$j+1;
    }
    header("Location: 12.html"); //logout after taking attendance..
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: There are couple of SQL syntax errors in your scripts.

Comment: You can find if any records exist for an user if count is more than 0 then you have to update else insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_value = $date[$value];
$present_value = $present[$value];
$absent_value = $absent[$value];

$check_result = mysql_query("selct count(*) from Attendence where Fac_name = '$id' AND date = '$date_value' AND Present = '$present_value' AND Absent = '$absent_value'  ");
if($check_result == 0)
{
    // insert query
}
else
{
    // update query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your INSERT query line has Syntax error Please correct it . You have only three row names - Fac_name, date, Present,  Absent but are inserting 5 values. Besides that quotes are not used correctly